# HTML5 <span> equivalent in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How would one achieve having different styles for letters in a flutter Text() widget.
Example : https://codepen.io/sifudiep/pen/MWKabJq,

```
<body>
  <p style="font-size: 80px">
    <span style="color: blue">+</span>03:45
  </p>
</body>
```

first letter is blue however the other ones are black.

Comment: [Check this out](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Widget you are looking for is RichText. It works pretty similar to . Have a look at the official docs here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Alternatively, TextSpan is also something to look into: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextSpan-class.html